# Should I put a comma in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Do I need a comma after, "think"

"When people think in regard to education, they typically associate the idea with school teachers."

"When people think, in regard to education, they typically associate the idea with school teachers."

Comment: It is exactly as wrong as your comma after "after".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider re-positioning the word "think" and just say,

> When people regard education, they typically think of teachers.

In this form, you don't need both think and regard, since they have similar meanings.
*In regard to* is an idiom that means *referring to,* while definitions of *regard* include: *consider or take into account* and *relating to* or *concerning* [a subject]. So, if you restructure the sentence, you will not need to insert a comma.

If you want to keep the same structure, you do not need a comma, because the complete phrase that means *to consider* would be: *think in regard to.* Putting a comma after think would split the phrase.

Comment: Not only would it split the phrase, but the big things is that it would also create a parenthetical, without which the sentence reads "When people think, they typically associate the idea with school teachers", which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct edit. You are correct in both regards.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct, but indicate different usage.

The case where you would put a comma after "think" is known as [parenthetical punctuation](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_for_parenthesis.htm).

> When people think (in regard to education), they typically associate
>   the idea with school teachers.

The parentheses are replaced with commas (obviously dropping the double comma).

If you don't intend "in regard to education" to be a parenthetical aside, then don't use the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, in regard to the question of setting the particular phrase within commas, that it is appropriate for readability.

Comment: After rereading that question, my comment was better for readability of longer sentences. I agree with the comment that both forms of the sentence Ariel presented would be grammatically acceptable. Setting the phrase in commas actually emphasizes education. I liked how Cindy Page restructured the sentence, too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/448063)